# webClient issue - Between ReactorClientHttpConnector and httpClient

Tags: httpclient, netty, webclient, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am facing a problem with versions , first let me explain the problem.
I have the below code :

```
public WebClient createWebClient() throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forClient()
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .build();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));

        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(endpointURL)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .filter(errorHandlingFilter())
                .build();
    }
```

with spring-web version 5.2.3 and netty version 0.9.3 the part with the clientConnector is working fine.
Now the version I have is 5.0.11 (ONLY) and then this part of the code stops to work with the error :

```
incompatible types: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient cannot be converted to java.util.functi
on.Consumer<? super reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOptions.Builder>
```

Is there any alternative with the older version of spring-web?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The `HttpClientOptions` has been removed from reactor-netty in its 0.8.x generation, and you're effectively trying to use a 2 years old Spring Framework generation with a 9 months old release.

The Spring team is trying hard to maintain compatibility, but in the case of reactor netty, this is still a project in its 0.x phase and API changes/repackaging are still expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply =) , well I thought it would be the case.
Is that the only way to use SSL with webClient ?

Comment: I don't think SSL configuration is the issue here: even if you get it to work, there's no guarantee that those two versions will work correctly at runtime. I'd say using compatible versions is the first issue you should work on here.